# ng-options with multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a select that has a filter set to not show the 'public' string in an array (public, publicExtra and private) if a specific condition is met in the ng-if. But now I discovered that that is not the only condition required and it seems like I have to duplicate the select with different conditions in order to achieve what I want, this becomes very messy. Is there a way to create a filter in the controller and set the conditions there and then show the filter in the activate the filter on the select if all the conditions are met? Thanks in advance.

````
<select ng-model="elb_instance.use_vpc"
                    ng-if="elb_instance['new_record?']"
                    ng-options="('Subnet: ' + type) for type in elb_instance.vpc_names_with_subnet_types_for_elb[elb_instance.vpc_name] | filter: '!public' : true"
                    ng-show="elb_instance.vpc_name"
                    id="use_vpc"
                    class="input-medium">
                    <option value="">Select subnet</option>
            </select>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a custom filter with arg: `| myfilter:conditions`

```
<select ng-model="elb_instance.use_vpc"
        ng-if="elb_instance['new_record?']"
        ng-options="('Subnet: ' + type) for type in elb_instance.vpc_names_with_subnet_types_for_elb[elb_instance.vpc_name] | myfilter:conditions"
        ng-show="elb_instance.vpc_name">
    <option value="">Select subnet</option>
</select>
```

where `myfilter` can be something like:

```
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, conditions) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
       if(conditions.aaa == true /* and other rules... */) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }
        else if(conditions.bbb == true){
          filtered.push(item);
        }        
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

where `items` are `elb_instance.vpc_names_with_subnet_types_for_elb[elb_instance.vpc_name]`

Comment: So items in the function would have to be elb_instance.vpc_names_with_subnet_types_for_elb[elb_instance.vpc_name] and item would have to be type?

Comment: yes, but filter is invoked before you get `item` in `ng-repeat`. Into the filter you decide what to put into `filtered` list.

Comment: some old example I found, can help u: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0LMJzUiJy0NO9Hk0oWt?p=preview&preview

Comment: Maybe I did not explain the problem correctly. My case might be a bit different than that. elb_instance.vpc_names_with_subnet_types_for_elb[elb_instance.vpc_name] generates an array from a dynamic list ["public","publicExtra","private"]. I need to be able to exclude any one single item in that array based on a condition. So, for example, if condition a and condition b are true then show publicExtra and Private but exclude public. If condition a and condition c are true then show public and private but exclude publicExtra. Not sure if this make sense. Sorry for the back and forth.

Comment: please use my plunker and put your relevant code there